# problems with separate function

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I am trying to separate 1 column "A1A2" into 2, A1 and A2.

```
head(merged2)             
SNP        A1A2   P
1:12321    AG     3 
2:1231232  TC     12
8:1231321  GG     13
```

I want:

```
SNP        A1    A2   P
1:12321    A     G    3 
2:1231232  T     C    12
8:1231321  G     G    13
```

I tried:

```
merged3 <- merged2 %>% separate( A1A2, c( "A1", "A2" ) )
```

But this is leading to NA's in the second column:

```
SNP        A1    A2       P
1:12321    A     <NA>    3 
2:1231232  T     <NA>    12
8:1231321  G     <NA>    13
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to get the code to cooperate?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact output you're getting? For column A1, I get just the same values as you had in A1A2, and for column A2, all `NA`, all of which matches what I'd expect given the default `sep` argument in `separate`. Take a look at the docs to see how columns are split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `extract`, if that works for you:

```
df %>% extract(A1A2, into = c('A1','A2'), regex = '(.)(.)')
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  SNP       A1    A2        P
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1:12321   A     G         3
2 2:1231232 T     C        12
3 8:1231321 G     G        13
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `sep` argument, which by default separates on non-alphanumeric characters.

Here, one solution is to use a number for `sep`, which indicates at which position to cut:

```r
merged2 %>%
    separate( A1A2, c( "A1", "A2" ), sep = 1 )
#>         SNP A1 A2  P
#> 1   1:12321  A  G  3
#> 2 2:1231232  T  C 12
#> 3 8:1231321  G  G 13
```